# Getting 404 errors when trying to integrate Google Firestore in my project

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a web project where I want to integrate Google Firestore to store some of the data. The integration seemed straightforward at first, but I'm running into issues I don't understand.

In my main.js file, I've set up the Firestore as follows:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  // ... configuration details
};

initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = getFirestore();
const colReg = collection(db, 'blogEntries');

getDocs(colReg).then((snapshot) => {
    console.log(snapshot.docs);
});
```

When I run my project locally and navigate to it in my browser, I am expecting to see some logs in the console showing the Firestore data. However, instead of the expected results, I get these errors:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Blog</title>
    <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
</head>
```

However, when I load the page, I get the following errors in the console:

GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/firebase/app net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/firebase/firestore 404 (Not Found)

I've triple-checked the paths and everything seems right. I've also looked into Firebase documentation to see if there's anything I missed, but couldn't find anything relevant.

Is there something obvious I'm missing? Or is there a common mistake new Firebase users make that could lead to this? I'd appreciate any guidance or tips on how to solve this issue.